# Angular маршрутизация

Tags: angular, маршрутизация

Мне нужна Ваша помощь. Я пытаюсь сделать страницу входа, а также маршрут для восстановления пароля. То есть, я нахожусь на url `/login` и пытаюсь перейти на url `/reset_password`, чтобы восстановить пароль. Оно работает, но когда я переключаюсь, у меня есть URL-адрес, сформированный как `/login/reset_password`. Как сделать так, чтобы он выглядел по-другому, а именно `/reset_password?` (при переключении на страницу восстановления пароля) Спасибо

Роуты

```
let routes : Routes = [
{path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
{path: ':/reset_password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent}]
```

login.component.html

```
<div class="login_component">
      <div class="login_form_block">
      <div><p>Войти в систему</p></div>
<form class="login_form">
      <div><input/></div>
      <button>Enter</button>
</form>
      <div>
          Восстановить пароль
          <a routerLink="reset_password">Forgot Password</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а почему у вас роут `:/reset_password`, а не `reset_password`?

Comment: будет ошибка `Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login/reset_password'`

Comment: `<a routerLink="/reset_password">Forgot Password</a>`

Comment: Спасибо, работает))